# Open SQL CE .sdf in SQL Server 2005 or 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-ce

is there a way to import SQL CE .sdf to SQL Server 2005 or 2008?

Comment: @Ashok, which version of SQL-CE you are using. 2.0, 3.0 or 3.5??

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL CE .sdf version is 3.0 or 3.5 you can directly open in SSMS.

But if your file version is 1.0 or 2.0, then you need to upgrade your .sdf file to 3.5 using Database Upgrade Tool, you can find more info here [Upgrade SQL Server Compact 2.0 By Using the Database Upgrade Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173006.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use my SQL Server Compact Toolbox (standalone or VS add-in) to migrate your .sdf file to a SQL Server database.